# i want php api responce in one array list

Tags: php, arraylist, response

```
$MobileNo = $_POST['MobileNo']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblLotProcessStatus WHERE MobileNo = $MobileNo" ; 
$result = sqlsrv_query($pdo,$query); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,(SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)))
{ 
    if($row)
    { 
        $status=array(); 
        array_push($status,$row); 
        $response["status"] = $status; 
        $response["responce_code"] = 200; 
        $response["error_code"] = 0; 
        $response["error_msg"] = "status avialable"; 
        echo json_encode($response); 
    }
```

JSON output:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "status": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "strPartyCode": "00000000",
            "intLotID": "257949",
            "MobileNo": "9879105144                                        ",
            "Messages": "Lot No : 15023  on Loop Ager/Poly started.,Style:PIGMENT PRINT",
            "status": 0,
            "Type": "PF ",
            "dtmDateTime": {
                "date": "2016-02-22 12:00:00.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
            },
            "strLotNo": "N 15023",
            "strProcess": "Loop Ager/Poly,Style:PIGMENT PRINT",
            "strStatus": " started."
        }
    ],
    "responce_code": 200,
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_msg": "status avialable"
}{
    "error": false,
    "status": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "strPartyCode": "00000000",
            "intLotID": "246654",
            "MobileNo": "9879105144                                        ",
            "Messages": "Lot No : 8191  on Compacting complited.,Style:DYED",
            "status": 0,
            "Type": "PF ",
            "dtmDateTime": {
                "date": "2015-03-09 15:00:00.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
            },
            "strLotNo": "N 8191",
            "strProcess": "Compacting,Style:DYED",
            "strStatus": " complited."
        }
    ],
    "responce_code": 200,
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_msg": "status avialable"
}
```

Comment: i write above code and get the result but not in array list

Comment: Hi Nency, this is difficult to read, edit your question, and add your code from the comment above to your question.  Use the code sample button for code blocks.

Comment: Refer to this [ask], also what is your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: what you are expecting result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are adding all of the details to a new array and then outputing the `json_encode()`ed data each time.  Instead you need to build up 1 array of data and encode it after loading all of the rows from the database...

```
$response = ["responce_code" => 200, "error_code" => 0, 
    "error_msg" => "status avialable" ];
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,(SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)))
{
    $response["status"][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Just an aside - there may be a few spelling mistakes (assuming English spelling) in some of the data, perhaps

```
$response = ["response_code" => 200, "error_code" => 0, 
    "error_msg" => "status available" ];
```